# replace crontab file with -e

Tags: cron

Anyone know a way to give a file into crontab -e ? I cannot use the regular form of crontab giving it a path but still need to replace the whole contents.

Perhaps setting EDITOR to something?

Comment: *Why* can't you use the "regular form"?

Comment: I don't know why he can't. But I have a case where I need to "delay tasks" for a few hours due to network maintenance. As this is recurrent, I want to create a script to create a backup from the cron file, delay tasks and save it. Later, I want to rollback those changes.

Answer (score 35):

You can source cron jobs from a file into your crontab using

```
crontab /path/to/cron/file/name
```

To make it more explicit for readability's sake, use the arrow `<` for sourcing.

```
crontab < /path/to/cron/file/name
```

Sourcing the cron jobs this way can throw error `errors in crontab file, can't install` in case the crontab entry you have are syntactically invalid in terms of scheduling, so make sure the cron entries are correct.

Also note that this will completely discard existing cronjobs and load the ones which are there in the file you pass, so it might help to save existing cron entries in a file using `crontab -l > cron.backup`

**EDIT**

In case you are looking for a way to change your default editor (to gedit or vi or something else) and not for a way to source cronjobs from file, you can export the `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` Path variables

```
export VISUAL=vim
export EDITOR=vim
```